# If an endogenous explanatory variable is serially correlated does it mean that its lags are also endogenous?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, economic-growth, endogeneity

in panel data when examining economic growth determinants lags are often used to account for endogeneity of explanatory variables. However if the explanatory variable is serially correlated, does it mean that its lags are also endogenous and therefore should not be used as proxies or instruments?